# How to align a Text and CircularProgressIndicator Composable so that they stay together even after text grows from 1 to 2,3 lines

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, composable

I want to place a CircularProgressIndicator at the end of a text. Textview can be one line or two or three.
Current code :

```
@Composable
fun Test() {
    Row(
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(horizontal = 16.dp)
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "Sample text to show large text view on screen. Switching to view in 3, 2, 1",
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f, false)
        )
        CircularProgressIndicator(Modifier.size(20.dp, 20.dp))
    }
}
```

Sample view:
[image]